# Is there any way to move line from right to left in html?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move a horizontal line from right to left and when it while it moves it's length should reduce and become zero.

I tried with animation but it happening in loop. It should happen only once.

Here is the code which I tried

```css
div {
    top: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    background: black;
    position: relative;
    animation: myfirst 10s 2;
    animation-direction: initial;
    overflow-y: hide;
}

@keyframes myfirst {
    0% {
        background: black;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
    }
    100% {
        background: white;
        left: 100%;
        top: 0px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Is this correct or there is better way to achieve it?

[image]

Adding image for more clarity. Here on load black line has width 100% with time it's width reducing.

Comment: It can be useful to add image with current and desired state. It can make it easier to help you.

Comment: /* animation-fill-mode: forwards */ will end the animation in the state it was ended in

Answer (score 0):

Try to set this one:

```
div{
    animation: myfirst 10s 1;
}
```

The last parameter of "animation" is for animation iteration count and you have it defined as "2".

Comment: I tried it . That black line comes back. I am trying to make its width from 100% to 0

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing it in a Codepen it's kinda hard to tell what's going on.

The correct animation property for one count would be `animation: myfirst 10s 1;`

However if that doesn't work, can you try adding `animation-iteration-count: 1;`?

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping the values of `left` from the below section and it will give you your desired result. And for iteration count you can set the value here `animation: myfirst 10s 2;`  from `2 to 1`.

```
  0% {
    background: black;
    left: 100%;  -->this one
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background: white;
    left: 0px;  --> this one
    top: 0px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    div {
      top: 100px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 5px;
      background: black;
      position: relative;
      animation: myfirst 10s 1;
      animation-direction: initial;
      overflow-y: hide;
    }
    
    @keyframes myfirst {
      0% {
        background: black;
        left: 100%;
        top: 0px;
      }
      100% {
        background: white;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div></div>
</body>

</html>
```